# Get a instance of an object, does it belong to the class?

Tags: c#, class, oop, static

This is my class:

```
public class Boots
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Size { get; private set; }

    public Boots(string Name, int Size)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Size = Size;
    }
}
```

I want to create a method that gets a boot by name from the database. 
Were should I put that method in OOP thinking? The method doesn't belong to an instance of a boot but it belongs, in my opinion, to the class.

Is the proper way to do this by having a static method inside the boot class that returns an instance

```
public static Boots GetBoots(string Name)
{
    //Get boot from db and creates a Boots by calling its constructor
    return new Boots(.....);
}
```

Comment: Search "active record", this has been discussed plenty of times before.

Comment: You might create a `BootsRepository` which fetches and saves instances of `Boots`.  (I'm struggling to find a better name than `Boots`, too.  Because plural collections of that class are going to be semantically weird.  Maybe call it `BootPair`?)

Comment: You will need some kind of ffactory that creates in-memory-objects from your database-entities. This barely belongs to the actual feature-class IMO.

Comment: The BootsRepository idea is good. Then I get a clear separation from the instance class. (Sorry for naming the class Boots...I should force the business to separate them into one and one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the question is good, but there is a lack of information if for example you use some ORM, repositories or this is just odata requests, cause I'm quite sure you got already some bunch of code :) My approach would be using the repository pattern for that cases, but for such simple case you can also think about active record pattern. Remember to keep things simple and not over design if there is no need.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will look into repository pattern and active record pattern. Lets say Im not using a ORM and just get a dataset from a database command returned to the GetBoots funktion. If you have time, could you give me an example of the two patterns you suggested?

Comment: First thing is that if you use MS SQL I suggest to use Stored Procedure instead of function to that kind of thing. From design perspective functions should be used more for calculation activities - not for gathering data. The second thing is that in that case I would avoid Active Record Pattern and go  with repository. I guess that you use ADO.NET so look at this article: http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/04/ado-net-the-right-way/